# In TYPO3 tx_news, how to filter by categories?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In tx_news, filtering by categories via Typoscript doesn't work as expected

```
  settings {
        limit = 5
        orderBy = datetime
        orderDirection = asc
        overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)
        categories = 24
  }
```

The categories filter is not being applied. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution, `categoryConjunction = and` must be applied

```
  settings {
        limit = 5
        orderBy = datetime
        orderDirection = asc
        overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)
        categories = 24
        categoryConjunction = and
  }
```

I found this on http://webdesign-forum.net/thread-2510.html

Comment: Does not work for me. I am trying to use ajax paging, based on a page type, but all news are shown, the category filter seems to be ignored.